# Matlab Simulink, how to pass a string as a mask parameter?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am currently developing a custom matlab function simulink block.

I have 2 normal inputs and a third input as a mask parameter in a combobox. If I modify my function so that the parameter should be a number everything works(you just have to tick the evaluate checkbox in the mask editor), if I use a function that needs that parameter to be a string  I receive the classic error:

Expression 'parametername' for initial value of data 'parametername' must evaluate to specified type string.

So my question is how can I set my block to receive a string as an input parameter?

If I turn the parameter to  a normal input everything works, but I don't like to have such type of input organization.

It would be still okay to have as real input parameter number but show in the combobox corresponding names.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this? If so, please feel free to posting an answer to your own question if you think it may be helpful to future readers.